# ?Why with multiple promises their respective thens are not are not glued together but intertwined instead?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

When you run this code

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('setTimeout')
},0)

console.log('start');

async function first() {
  await console.log('first_resolve');
  await console.log('first_then_1');
  await console.log('first_then_2');
}
async function second() {
  await console.log('second_resolve');
  await console.log('second_then_1');
  await console.log('second_then_2');
}

first()
second()


Promise.resolve(console.log('third_resolve'))
  .then(() => console.log('third_then_1'))
  .then(() => console.log('third_then_2'))
Promise.resolve(console.log('fourth_resolve'))
  .then(() => console.log('fourth_then_1'))
  .then(() => console.log('fourth_then_2'))

console.log('end');
```

you get this in console

```
start
first_resolve
second_resolve
third_resolve
fourth_resolve
end
first_then_1
second_then_1
third_then_1
fourth_then_1
first_then_2
second_then_2
third_then_2
fourth_then_2
setTimeout
```

The same is true for a simple Promise with then chain.

I do understand why setTimeout is at the end (it's a macrotask and macrotask have to wait for microtasks).

But Promise and then are both microtasks. So the question is why with multiple promises their respective thens are not glued together but intertwined instead?

As I expected the following output:

```
start
first_resolve
first_then_1
first_then_2
second_resolve
second_then_1
second_then_2
third_resolve
third_then_1
third_then_2
fourth_resolve
fourth_then_1
fourth_then_2
end
setTimeout
```

Comment: Other than `setTimeout`, there is no asynchronous code here. Throwing `async` / `await` in front of something doesn't implicitly make it asynchronous

Comment: Well thats basically a Promise. If you rewrite it in promise with then chain you'll get the same result.

Comment: because that's what asynchronous functions do -- you can have multiple async functions going simultaneously. If you want the information as you've presented it, you either need to `.then` chain your first call like `first().then(...)` OR you need to put appropriate `await` in front of the functions.

Comment: "The same is true for a simple Promise with then chain." - can you show us your code for that? Because this works for me: `first().then(() => second())`

Comment: I think you'll find the answer in the _Description_ section here ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Description

Comment: I'd like to add that the reason the `setTimeout` goes last is because most Browsers default to 4 milliseconds if you pass `0` as your milliseconds, so the rest of the code was faster.

Comment: @Jhecht, Look at update `first().then(...)` doesn't work. What do you mean by "appropriate `await`" though?

Comment: @Rup, by "then chain" I didn't mean chain of promises. I meant seperate promises with isoletated then chains for each (see update above)

Comment: OK, well I think danh's answer covers this anyway? If you write `await first(); await second();` then you require the first() promise or chain to complete before starting second(). If you just write `first(); second();` then you do not.

Comment: @Rup, I understand how to get what I want (danh's answer). I don't quite understand why `second_then_1` resolve faster then `first_then_2`? And given that all promises take time to resolve would it result in sompletly different order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected results would only be expected if the two async functions, `first` and `second`, were invoked sequentially.  This can be demonstrated as follows...

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('setTimeout')
},0)

console.log('start');

async function first() {
  await console.log('first_resolve');
  await console.log('first_then_1');
  await console.log('first_then_2');
}
async function second() {
  await console.log('second_resolve');
  await console.log('second_then_1');
  await console.log('second_then_2');
}

async function opExperiment() {
  await first()
  await second()
  console.log('end');
}

opExperiment()
```

**EDIT**

Responding to the OP's edit.  The two blocks of promise code after the async functions are subject to the same rules.  To have these promises run sequentially, they must be await-ed or conjoined by `then()`.  Demonstrating again...

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('setTimeout')
}, 0)

console.log('start');

async function first() {
  await console.log('first_resolve');
  await console.log('first_then_1');
  await console.log('first_then_2');
}
async function second() {
  await console.log('second_resolve');
  await console.log('second_then_1');
  await console.log('second_then_2');
}


async function opExperiment() {
  await first()
  await second()

  await Promise.resolve(console.log('third_resolve'))
    .then(() => console.log('third_then_1'))
    .then(() => console.log('third_then_2'))
  await Promise.resolve(console.log('fourth_resolve'))
    .then(() => console.log('fourth_then_1'))
    .then(() => console.log('fourth_then_2'))

  console.log('end');
}

opExperiment()
```

Comment: so what will be an explanation for original behavior in terms of event loop then?

Comment: @WhatEver - I'm not sure what can be said with certainty across implementations (even across executions) about the sequence of async execution where the sequence hasn't been explicitly stated in the code.  Initiating the functions as you do is roughly like Promise.all() for all of them.  This doesn't guarantee a specific start (and certainly not end) sequence for the promises passed

Comment: so there is no specific order with thens per se? Why then `second_then_1` resolves faster then `first_then_2` every time given they both resolve immediately?

Comment: Also, looking at the sequence you've observed, it looks sensible to me:  first() starts executing, starts the first_resolve.  While that's happening, second() was invoked (right away after the queuing of the first_resolve timeout because we didn't await first), by the time first_resolve logs, second_resolve is ready to log, and while that's happening, first_then_1 has finished, and so on.  It's the logging that is taking all of the time.  It seems intuitive that these would interleave in the way you have observed (although again, it would be a mistake to *depend* on this behavior)

Comment: so I guess it will depend on time it take for promise to resolve then. Thnx.